# Monospace a text

Tags: html, css

How can i monospace the data shown in the table text with grayish background 
Please suggest something apart from bootstrap class test-monospace because it is not working because of the background being white .
I want the student name to come as a monospace text

```
<td >
@if(isset($student->name))
{{ $student->name }}
@else
@lang('NA')
@endif
</td>
```

Comment: This would be CSS or within a `<pre>` tag, Nothing to do with PHP or Laravel.

Comment: Set the font the courier

Comment: @aynber yes the pre tag worked thanks for the help can you please tell how can i have the line splitted . suppose if i get an id abcd12345678 and i use pre tag in it how can i have it in multi line because it is taking up a lot of space .